# XPath - getting data including HTML tags

Tags: html, wordpress, xpath

I have Wordpress with Web Scraper tool (PHP in background) that uses XPath to retreive data from other websites.

I'm facing a problem where I get all needed data, but these data are stripped from HTML tags.

XPath formula I'm using:

```
//table/tbody/tr[td//text()[contains(., 'FFF')]]
```

Data I'm using:

```
<table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>First</th>
                    <th>Second</th>
                    <th>G</th>
                    <th>Z</th>
                    <th>C</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1.</td>
                        <td>D</td>
                        <td>FFF</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">6</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">0</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2.</td>
                        <td>C</td>
                        <td>YYY</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">4</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">1</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3.</td>
                        <td>B</td>
                        <td>ZZZ</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">4</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">0</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4.</td>
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td>FFF</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">3</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">0</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">0</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Result I'm getting:

```
1. D FFF 6 0 0 4. A FFF 3 0 0
```

Result I need:

```
    <tr>
                        <td>1.</td>
                        <td>D</td>
                        <td>FFF</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">6</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">0</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">0</td>
                    </tr>

<tr>
                        <td>4.</td>
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td>FFF</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">3</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">0</td>
                        <td class="txt-c">0</td>
                    </tr>
```

Tool I'm using: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-web-scraper/

Exact shortcode I'm using in wordpress (url changed):

```
[wpws url='https://myweb.comm' query='%2F%2Ftable%2Ftbody%2Ftr%5Btd%2F%2Ftext()%5Bcontains(.%2C%20%27FFF%27)%5D%5D' output='html' query_type='xpath' querydecode='1']
```

All I need is same filtered HTML-tagged table.

Thank you for answers.

Comment: Please add the programming language or tool you are using. Make sure everyone can reproduce your issue by adding all relevant code or steps you have taken. Also, it is a bit unclear what _exactly_ the result should look like.

Comment: If you actually get text as a result, then the XPath expression is fine. It is the Wordpress Scraper plugin that treats the result in the wrong way. Are you sure the plugin does not let you define whether to retrieve actual HTML or always extract text? There seems to be a parameter called `output` where one of the values is "text".

Comment: Hello Mathias, thank you for your answer. Yes I can set output as html (it's set by default but I also tried to set it in output parameter) but the result is still same. I'm using this plugin in other cases with different XPath expressions and the result is fine. This is the first time I have this problem.

Comment: It's not possibe to reproduce the result because you did not disclose the site URL, but I think this might be a bug in the Scraper plugin. The XPath expression should by all means return `tr` elements, not text - and `output='html'` should keep HTML markup. Another explanation is that the markup is returned, but your way of _looking at_ the data does not show HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your thoughts.

I have finally managed to get it working. The plugin itself is working fine. Only problem was missing table pair tag in Wordpress post where shortcode is used.

**Solution:**

```
<table>
[wpws url='https://yoururl.com' query='your query' output='html' query_type='xpath']
</table>
```